# while trying to convert time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I am using R language and while I was trying to convert my data frame to time series data I am finding some error messages. My data is for 106 days. What frequency should I use in the code?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! For someone to help, you need to give a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Edit your question and provide some of your data via `dput(head(Australia_2))`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post pictures of code or errors. This makes them more difficult to search in the future.